# Receive serial Data from external device via Bluetooth using android

Tags: android

I am very new to android development and have developed an app that transmit data from my tab to external Bluetooth printer and prints the data and now i wanted to receive serial data from external device via Bluetooth.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check BluetoothChat Sampple Application in SDK Folder. The nice example of Bluetooth Communication.

Comment: What is your question?